# Где найти путь по которому Docker daemon подключается к сокету?

Tags: linux, docker, daemon

Выполняю команду

```
user@user-ET2013I:~$ docker ps -a
```

Получаю ответ

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Подозреваю, что это потому, что раньше у меня стоял докер десктоп, но, видимо, не удалился, и где-то остались старые настройки. Где найти указанный путь, чтобы поменять настройки?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод команд `which docker`, `sudo netstat -lp | grep docker`. Для эксперимента можете также создать каталог `/home/user/.docker/desktop/` и сделать в нём символическую ссылку на `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Ещё вариант: можете вызывать не просто `docker`, а `/usr/bin/docker`